# Autoload Breakpoints in gdb

Tags: shell, debugging, gdb

is there a way to load breakpoints using the `x` commandline option (or may I be on the wrong way)

It seems it doesn't work as expected. Is there a **execute after load of executable** switch or command?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1) Gdb -x command line option requires a gdb script name. Specified script can contain a bunch of "break wherever" command to insert breakpoints.

2) I'm not sure there is specific switch to run executable, but you can use -ex run (so this: *gdb yourexecutable -ex run*) to load and start a program.

You can also combine more -ex switches like this:
*gdb yourexecutable -ex "break main" -ex run*.